# VBA to go to next blank cell in a range

Tags: excel, vba

Ok so here's what I need help with.

When I complete cell entry in Column X it then goes to the next blank cell of Column E.

So if I complete X6, it then goes to Column E row 7. I also need this to occur every time, so if Cell X7 is completed then it goes to E8, X8 then goes to E9 and so on..

Here's the VBA code I managed to figure out but I don't think it works to what I need.

```
Sub MOVETO()
'
' MOVETO Macro
'

'
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 10
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 8
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    Range("E7").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer from somewhere else thats worked as i intended it too.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
  If Target.Column > 24 Then Cells(Target.Row + 1, "E").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 24 Then
    Target.Offset(1, -19).Select
End If
End Sub
```

You can't past it in normal Modul but in Object for example Sheet1 in VBA
[image]